# Specify approval sort order for PullRequest Azure-Repos

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request

How can I specify in which order the approval of a pull request needs to be done.
Is this possible at all?
[image]

To archive approver number 2. can only approve after the first one had already approved.

Comment: I don't think it's possible out of the box, at least there is no configuration available in Azure DevOps which would enable such functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I specify in which order the approval of a pull request needs to be done.

AFAIK, there is no such way to achieve this at this moment.

Personally, it doesn't seem to make sense. Since those reviewers are set as Optional.

That means their votes don't affect whether the PR is done, it just helps us gather their opinions. Then the sequence is not so important.

If the order of votes is important to you, then they should be in Required, in which case the order will again be meaningless, since the PR requires the consent of all the people in Required to complete.

So this order doesn't seem to make much sense.

If you have an order-specific need, please describe the scenarios in which it applies and what it means to do so.

Comment: Hi, yes on screenshot it is optional. Just tested sth. But it is intended to be changed as required soon.       So the point of this is to have multiple stages of approvals in a strict order. For example having a code review followed up by a manual test provider by different persons.